# Receive POST method values in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I am trying to send values from one jsp to another directly.
I am using `extjs` to receive the submitted values.
I have no clue how to receive the sent data. I prefer sending the data through POST method.
Below is the code

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
     url: 'hello.jsp',
     method:'POST',
     params:{"abc":abc,"xyz":xyz},
    success: received,
    failure: function(){alert('failure');}
});
```

To retreive the values in hello.js (linked to hello.jsp), I have no clue.
Can anyone please let me know if there is any in-built method in `extjs`?

I tried using GET method to send and receive but still the sent values weren't received properly. I used the below code:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
     url: 'hello.jsp?xyxz=xyz&abc=abc',
     method:'GET',
    success: received,
    failure: function(){alert('failure');}
});
```

receiving part:

```
function getSearchParameters() {
      var prmstr = window.location.search.substring(1);
      alert(prmstr);
}
```

the above alert didn't give me desired results.

Comment: They have a good [example in the docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Ajax-method-request)

Comment: Let us assume that I am sending details successfully through POST method, I am unable to understand the receiving of data. That doc doesn't explain that.

Comment: I added an answer to this question and an example fiddle for demonstration.  It should hopefully help explain what is going on in the success function better and what a typical response from your web service would look like.

Answer (score 4):

A fiddle of this answer is available [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/aa7)

If you are returning `json` from your web service.  Then it would look similar to this example: (you can do `xml` or even return `html` for that matter)

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [{
        "FirstName": "John",
        "LastName": "Smith"
    }, {
        "FirstName": "Josh",
        "LastName": "Anon"
    }]
}
```

And you ExtJs ajax request would look similar to this:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
            url:'example.json',
            success:function(response){
                //the response object
                console.log(response);
                //the body of the response as a string
                console.log(response.responseText);
                //convert the json to an object
                var jsonObj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                console.log(jsonObj);
                //and here is the first item in the array and the first name
                console.log(jsonObj.data[0].FirstName);
            }
        });
```

An explanation of what is going on in my success function:

- First I log the response.  This is what is originally returned from the `ajax` request it includes the body of the response from the server in the `responseText` property.  It includes other properties that could be useful (like status codes)
- Next I am logging the responseText to show that this is the response we were expecting from the server.  Note this is a `string` of the json
- Next we convert that string of json to a javascript object that we can utilize
- Lastly I am showing how I would be able to get the value of the first node of the data object in the json.

Answer (score 2):

Just update your success function like below.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
     url: 'hello.jsp',
     method:'POST',
     params:{"abc":abc,"xyz":xyz},
    success: function(jsonObj){
     //this jsonObj should contains data from your JSP page,now you can set this value to your HTML.
    },
    failure: function(){alert('failure');}
});
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, my question is how to receive on the end result jsp using extjs. By the way, am I setting the values in a wrong way?

Comment: in the end jsp you can get the values from request object(either using request.getParameter('') in case of GET or from body in case of POST method).Then you can set these values in the fields.

Comment: "from body in case of POST method" this is what I am unable to understand. How should I do that? Can you please edit your answer?

Comment: in case of POST method.                                   BufferedReader bf = request.getReader(); StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();                        while((line =bf.readLine())!=null){sb.append(line)};                                Now you can use bf data to set your fields.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about how to do this is a asp, but this is how to read POST values from ExtJS using php:

```
if (isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA)) {
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  $requestData = json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
}
```

$requestData should contain the POST data from the ExtJs Ajax call.